# Android: How to make async task sleep , while evaluating some condition

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have a `AsyncTask` in which I want to test a condition every 3 seconds.

When I call the `Thread.sleep(int)` method in it I get `Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()` error.

Below is my code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() 
    {

        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() 
        {
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), null, "Loading Categories...");
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while(mOnlinCouponCategoriesManager.isDownloading())
            {
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Log.e("Categories Section:", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            if(categoryAdapter  == null)
            {
                categoryAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_categorylist, mOnlineCategoriesCursor, new String[] {}, new int[] {});
                setListAdapter(categoryAdapter);
            }
            else
            {
                setListAdapter(categoryAdapter);
            }
            return null;
        }

    }.execute();

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list, null);
    return view;
}
```

Here is my stack trace

```
01-15 16:23:38.233: E/AndroidRuntime(31508): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
01-15 16:23:38.233: E/AndroidRuntime(31508): Process: in.coupondunia.androidapp, PID: 31508
01-15 16:23:38.233: E/AndroidRuntime(31508): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
01-15 16:23:38.233: E/AndroidRuntime(31508):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
01-15 16:23:38.233: E/AndroidRuntime(31508):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
01-15 16:23:38.233: E/AndroidRuntime(31508):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
01-15 16:23:38.233: E/AndroidRuntime(31508):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
01-15 16:23:38.233: E/AndroidRuntime(31508):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
01-15 16:23:38.233: E/AndroidRuntime(31508):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
01-15 16:23:38.233: E/AndroidRuntime(31508):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
01-15 16:23:38.233: E/AndroidRuntime(31508):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
01-15 16:23:38.233: E/AndroidRuntime(31508): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
01-15 16:23:38.233: E/AndroidRuntime(31508):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
01-15 16:23:38.233: E/AndroidRuntime(31508):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
01-15 16:23:38.233: E/AndroidRuntime(31508):    at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter$ChangeObserver.<init>(CursorAdapter.java:455)
01-15 16:23:38.233: E/AndroidRuntime(31508):    at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.init(CursorAdapter.java:176)
01-15 16:23:38.233: E/AndroidRuntime(31508):    at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.<init>(CursorAdapter.java:122)
01-15 16:23:38.233: E/AndroidRuntime(31508):    at android.support.v4.widget.ResourceCursorAdapter.<init>(ResourceCursorAdapter.java:54)
01-15 16:23:38.233: E/AndroidRuntime(31508):    at android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.<init>(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:63)
01-15 16:23:38.233: E/AndroidRuntime(31508):    at in.coupondunia.androidapp.adapters.CategoryAdapter.<init>(CategoryAdapter.java:27)
01-15 16:23:38.233: E/AndroidRuntime(31508):    at in.coupondunia.androidapp.fragments.online.OnlineCategoriesFragment$1.doInBackground(OnlineCategoriesFragment.java:80)
01-15 16:23:38.233: E/AndroidRuntime(31508):    at in.coupondunia.androidapp.fragments.online.OnlineCategoriesFragment$1.doInBackground(OnlineCategoriesFragment.java:1)
01-15 16:23:38.233: E/AndroidRuntime(31508):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
01-15 16:23:38.233: E/AndroidRuntime(31508):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
01-15 16:23:38.233: E/AndroidRuntime(31508):    ... 4 more
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity in.coupondunia.androidapp.HomeActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42843b18 V.E..... R......D 0,0-729,192} that was originally added here
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:348)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:116)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:99)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:94)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at in.coupondunia.androidapp.fragments.online.OnlineCategoriesFragment$1.onPreExecute(OnlineCategoriesFragment.java:59)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at in.coupondunia.androidapp.fragments.online.OnlineCategoriesFragment.onCreateView(OnlineCategoriesFragment.java:90)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:651)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-15 16:23:39.434: E/WindowManager(31508):     at android.app.ActivityTh
```

How Can I make async task wait for 3 seconds before it checks the condition?

Comment: Your error is not related to that `Thread.sleep()`. Do you create your `AsyncTask` from a background thread?

Comment: post stack trace, and read it, too

Comment: Waiting for an operation to finish by checking its state periodically is a bad idea. You should have a callback what is fired when the operation is done.

Comment: @kupsef asyn task provides call back functions. Do you have any other suggestion ?

Comment: This is how I would do it: 

"mOnlinCouponCategoriesManager" should have a startDownload(OnDownloadCompleted listener) method. When you call this, the download should begin, and as it finishes the listener's downloadCompleted() method should be called to inform the called about the completion. OnDownloadCompleted is an interface what the caller should provide.

This way, there is no need to make an other thread, just to check whether the download is completed or not. Not to mention that, you delay the showing of the result by a maximum of 3 seconds if you have bad luck.

Comment: @zapl I think the error is indeed not related to _Thread.sleep()_, but it happens because he creates a _new CategoryAdapter()_ from a background thread.

Comment: @18446744073709551615 You are correct.

Comment: yeah , moving the code CategoryAdapter code to ui thread worked out. thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, AsyncTask threads are a limited resource. Thread.sleep() does not seem to be a good style.

To get something repeated after a delay:

in Activity:

```
private Handler uiHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
```

in a method:

```
//uiHandler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);
uiHandler.postDelayed(myRunnable, ms_interval);
```

But this will not solve the problem with the exception.
Most likely, the error will disappear if you initialize your CategoryAdapter on the UI thread and probably (not sure) you will also have to use it from the same thread. But this probably is not what you want. Maybe you will have to write your own service thread, initialize a looper and a handler on this thread, and only then post (delayed) runnables to the handler.
If you do the latter, please check what happens with the background thread when the screen is turned by 90 degrees and the activities are re-created. You definitely don't want to leak threads and activities that are referenced from these threads because they have started them (non-static inner classes have an implicit pointer to the containing instance of the containing class, which means that a *new Runnable(){}* references the activity that has created it).

Answer (score 2):

I think it can be safer to user a [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) and a [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) to achieve this. Then you can program the execution every 3s and check for condition before each.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("Categories Section:", e.getMessage());
        }                       
    }
});
```